# Issue with logging on Openshift jboss using log4j

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, log4j, openshift

i am having a couple of issues regarding logging using OpenShift with log4j on jboss.

I am using a log4j properties file as follows but seem to be getting no log messages in the file. I have the log4j properties file in the following locations in my app;

- /src/log4j.properties
- Deployed Resources/WEB-INF/log4j.properties
- WebContent/WEB-INF/log4j.properties

Is there anything specific i need to do differently for JBoss ?

Thanks

```
log=/var/lib/openshift/52c0260d4382ec7329000120/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossas/deployments/Logs/HotOrNotLog.log
log4j.rootLogger=default.file.debug
# System.out.println appender
log4j.appender.default.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.default.out.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.default.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# File appender for DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.file.debug=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.debug.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.debug.file=${log}
log4j.appender.default.file.debug.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.file.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.debug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# File appender for INFO log4j.appender.default.file.info=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.info.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.info.file=${log}
log4j.appender.default.file.info.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.info.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.info.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# File appender for WARN log4j.appender.default.file.warn=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.warn.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.warn.file=${log}
log4j.appender.default.file.warn.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.default.file.warn.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.warn.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# File appender for ERROR
log4j.appender.default.file.error=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.error.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.error.file=${log}
log4j.appender.default.file.error.threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.default.file.error.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.error.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# File appender for FATAL
log4j.appender.default.file.fatal=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.fatal.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.fatal.file=${log}
log4j.appender.default.file.fatal.threshold=FATAL
log4j.appender.default.file.fatal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.fatal.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

**EDIT**

having looked in the jboss server logs (server.log in /var/lib/openshift/52c0260d4382ec7329000120/jbossas/logs) i can see the following

```
2014/03/31 17:29:58,393 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.hotornot.database.DBFactory).

2014/03/31 17:29:58,425 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

2014/03/31 17:29:58,426 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

however stack overflow suggests the properties file isn't in the class path - but it is in source as well as two other places lol

Comment: It looks like a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is needed as shown in [this](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2065) article (linked to by [this](http://ericsilva.org/2012/06/18/application-level-logging-in-openshift-using-apache-commons-logging-on-jbossas7/) article which shows how to separate the logging API from the logging implementation).

Comment: hmmm, i tried adding this file, still no joy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to put log4 props in the src/resources folder - its a maven issue as it appears it has a standard dir it checks for log4j props

Answer (score 1):

Two things that jump out.

1. None of the following are on the classpath:

   - /src/log4j.properties
   - Deployed Resources/WEB-INF/log4j.properties
   - WebContent/WEB-INF/log4j.properties

   Try `WEB-INF/classes` within your web application (depending on your build having it in `/src` should copy it over there).
2. Your first line is `log4j.rootLogger=default.file.debug`.  Shouldn't this be `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, default.file.debug`?  It should be a level, then a comma, then an appender.

Do you need all those appenders, anyway?  Wouldn't this be the same thing:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.file=${log}
log4j.appender.FILE.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is in later versions, in JBoss 4 there is a jboss-log4j.xml and i'd say that is used by default. You could check that file..